# Strategies for large databases with changing schemas

Tags: mysql, database, entity-attribute-value, bigdata

We have a mysql database table with hundreds of millions of rows. We run into issues with performing any kind of operation on it. For example, adding columns is becoming impossible to do with any kind of predictable time frame. When we want to roll out a new column the "ALTER TABLE" command takes forever so we dont have a good idea as to what the maintenance window is.

We're not tied to keeping this data in mysql, but I was wondering if there are strategies for mysql or databases in general, for updating schemas for large tables.

One idea, which I dont particularly like, would be to create a new table with the old schema plus additional column, and run queries against a view which unioned the results until all data could be moved to the new table schema.

Right now we already run into issues where deleting large numbers of records based on a where clause exit in error.

Ideas?

Comment: Might be a better question for the DBA Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can create a new table using an entity-attribute-value model.  This would have one row per entity and attribute, rather than putting the attribute in a new column.

This is particularly useful for sparse data.  Words of caution:  types are problematic (everything tends to get turned into strings) and you cannot define foreign key relationships.

EAV models are particularly useful for sparse values -- when you have attributes that only apply to a minimum number of roles.  They may prove useful in your case.

In NOSQL data models, adding new attributes or lists of attributes is simpler.  However, there is no relationship to the attributes in other rows.

Comment: Entity-attribute-value model would make retrieval way too slow. Everything would be a huge join.

We've considered common fields in regular columns, and a json blob for arbitrary attributes, but json is not very space efficient.

Another possibly option would be to move to a columnar database, but I'm not sure how that would affect performance. It's difficult to do an apples to apples comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Columnar databases (at least the one in MariaDB) is very frugal on space -- some say 10x smaller than InnoDB.  The shrinkage, alone, may be well worth it for 100M rows.

You have not explained whether your data is sparse.  If it is, the JSON is not that costly for space -- completely leave out any 'fields' that are missing; zero space.  With almost any other approach, there is at least some overhead for missing cells.

As you suggest, use regular columns for common fields.  But also for the *main* fields that you are *likely* to search on.  Then throw the rest into JSON.

I like to compress (in the client) the JSON string and use a `BLOB`.  This give 3x shrinkage over using uncompressed `TEXT`.

I dislike the one-row per attribute EAV approach; it is very costly in space, `JOINs`, etc, etc.

[*More thoughts*] on EAV.

Do avoid `ALTER` whenever possible.